# How can I refer to a Range in an Auto-Formatted Reply Email using VBA Excel?

Tags: html, excel, vba, email, hyperlink

I have the below code. Because I'm using .HTMLBody I need to use HTML tags within VBA. The recipient of the email will see a clickable value (hyperlink through "AHREF" in code) in the body of the email. Once clicked a newly composed Email opens which has some basic pre-populated text in the To, Subject and Body fields.

In the Body field I wish to refer to a value after "VOLUME:" that is placed in Range("A6") in my original Excel worksheet. Every time I change the value in Range("A6") the email will be sent again. The recipient will again click on the hyperlink and should see a changed value compared to the previous email. Is this possible?

```
  Sub Test()
 Dim oApp As Object
 Dim oEmail As Object


Dim Header As String
Dim Alpha As String

Dim olkPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
Const PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F"

Header = "<html>" & "<table cellpadding= 5>" & "<tr bgcolor=""#000080"">" 
& "<font color =""white"";font face =Calibri><b>" & "<td width = 250>" & 
Range("A5") & "</td>" & _
"<td align=""center"";td width= 60>" & Range("E5") & "</td>" & "</font> 
</b>" & "</tr>" & "</html>"

Alpha = "<tr bgcolor=""#F0F0F0"">" & "<font face =Calibri>" & "<td>" & 
Range("A6") & "</td>" & "<td align=""center"">" & "<A HREF='mailto: 
xxx@xxx.com&subject=***ENQUIRY***&Body=INSTRUCTION: EXTEND %0D%0DVOLUME: 
1000  %0D%0DCODE: 12345 '>" & _
     "<font color =""blue"">" & Range("E6") & "</td>" & "</A>" & "</font>" 
& "</tr>" & "</html>"

Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(0)
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With oEmail
   .To = ""
   .CC = ""
   .BCC = "xxx@xxx.com"
   .Subject = "Test"
   .HTMLBody = Header & Alpha
   .Display
  End With

     Set oEmail = Nothing
   Set oApp = Nothing
   Set colAttach = Nothing
   Set oAttach = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You already seem to be constructing the body of the email using a reference to Range("E6"). What is currently happening? Why is it not what you want?

Comment: Michael - thanks for your reply. Range("E6") has a value of 100 in my worksheet. Sending a email with Range("E6") in the body displays the value of 100 correctly in the body of the email. Also, the value of 100 is hyperlinked (clickable) in the body of the email. As soon as the recipient clicks on the hyperlinked 100, a new pre-formatted email opens. I would like to have that value 100 displayed in that newly opened email as well. If i change Range("E6") to say 101 and send a new email, the hyperlink is updated to 101 and once clicked, 101 should be in the body of the new email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the value from A6 in place of the 1000 that's currently there, you should just be able to construct the hyperlink string with a reference to Range("A6"), the same way you have in other parts of the overall html string:

```
Alpha = "<tr bgcolor=""#F0F0F0"">" & "<font face =Calibri>" & "<td>" & Range("A6") & "</td>" & "<td align=""center"">" & _
"<A HREF='mailto: xxx@xxx.com&subject=***ENQUIRY***&Body=INSTRUCTION: EXTEND %0D%0DVOLUME: " & Range("A6") & " %0D%0DCODE: 12345 '>" & _
"<font color =""blue"">" & Range("E6") & "</td>" & "</A>" & "</font>" & "</tr>" & "</html>"
```

Comment: Michael - works! This is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. If this has resolved your issue, please mark my answer as correct using the tick to the left. Thanks.